# Separate 2 networks with 1 Windows Server

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, routing, configuration, local-area-network

The situation is:

- I have 1 router 192.168.1.1, 1 switch, 1 windows server and a basic LAN of devices accessing it.
- I need to split into 2 **separate** LANs with full Internet access each, but isolated from each other.

Given that, the server is a Windows Server 2008 R2 with 2 NICs:

- NIC1: 192.168.1.2
- NIC2: 192.168.2.2

The router has no dhcp configuration.

Please, can anyone explain gracefully, step by step, what do I need to do? What would be the 2 NICs full configuration? What services do I need to install?

I don't want devices on either network to see devices on the other network, they must be completely separate.

I guess I'm missing the routing procedure step, but I have no idea how is that done.

For example: tell the server that devices with gateway 192.168.2.2 must send traffic for internet to 192.168.1.1 router.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows really isn't the right tool for this.  Get a router with more interfaces.

Comment: Configuring VLAN's and Inter-VLAN routing is probably the preferred and recommended way to do this.

Comment: @Zoredache, do you recommend me any router?

Answer (score 2):

Nobody is going to give you step-by-step instructions. Server Fault is not here to do your job for you.

My suggestion for you is as follows:

1. Configure two separate vLANs on your switch -- A and B
2. Configure a router for each vLAN.
   Depending on the equipment you have you may be able to do this with your existing router, or you may need to acquire a new one.

   - Do not configure your router(s) to pass traffic between the two vLANs
   - Configure NAT as necessary on your router (varies depending upon your upstream network).

Implementing these suggestions is left as a research exercise for you - and frankly if this doesn't point you in the right direction you need to bring in a professional to show you how this is done.
Basic network engineering is a little much for us to teach you on a Q&A site - its something you should be learning from an experienced mentor.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an old computer, just install pfsense. Easy to use and has many features.
http://www.pfsense.org/

Answer (score -1):

Router on a stick with sub-interfaces and 802.11q trunking to the physical router interface from the switch if its a managed sw.